# Manipulate class of a <path> inside a SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a JavaScript (pure, simple JS, no jQuery) inside a SVG where I grab a `<path>` via  document.getElementById(). Now I try to add a class 'active' to this  but I'm stuck.

Here's my (simplified) code so far:

```
var element = document.getElementById(myId);
//A console.log(element) returns the <path>-Object, so I guess this is working.

if (element) {
    //Add a class
}
```

I can get the current class(es) of the -Object:

```
console.log(element.className.baseVal);
```

But I can not add 'active' to this... I've tried several methods like e.g.

```
element.attr('class', className + ' active');
```

.. which returns

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<SVGPathElement> has no method 'attr'
```

Is there an easy way to do this in blank JavaScript? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setAttribute()` for javascript `.attr()` is jquery function.

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
element.setAttribute('class', className + ' active');
```

You were trying to do it in jquery's syntax